# Usb Tethering not working after update to 18.04

Tags: networking

I was able to connect to internet with usb tethering via Redmi Note 6 pro few days after the update, and now it suddenly stopped. I tried changing MAC from network settings of laptop as answered in similar question. But it hasn't helped me yet. Please help!

Comment: @starkus I am using my mobile phone. Earlier I just used to switch on USB tethering from the mobile. But now it doesn't give me internet access on my laptop.

Comment: One line gets added on top. It has TYPE: ethernet. Do you want to see exact output?

Comment: Device : enp0s20f0u1

Comment: Yes sir. Gets added in the list after enabling it. In settings under "network", I can see USB Ethernet as connected with the same name as in the list.

Comment: This  issue  Solved ?